# MVC problemas para apuntar direcciones

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Amigos tengo el siguiente form que apunta a un metodod e mi controlador **CreateFolder** no tengo ningun problema para correr mi método, no obstante , no me está devolviendo lo vista que quiero ... es decir yo siempre espero a que me mande a **CreateFolder/index** y trata de mandarme a un lugar que no existe en mi proyecto algo como **CreateFolder/CreateFolder** y pues no es lo que busco aquí les dejo mi código.

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFolder(FormCollection form) {

  if (micode) {
    //todo mi code bien hermoso

    return View();

  } else {
    //si algo falla
    return View(); //yo quisiera incluso mandar a otra vista si tengo error
    //así si pueden apoyarme con eso estaría genial aunque no es parte mi pregunta

  }

  //end method
}
```

```html
//no sé porque pero pienso que es algo de este lado
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFolder", "CreateFolder", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-control" })) 
{
<label>Elija un banco:</label> @Html.DropDownList("dropList", new SelectList(new[] { "Bancomer", "Banamex", "Santander", "Banorte" }), new { required = "required" })
<br />
<br />
<label>Agregue un archivo:</label> @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file", required = "required" })
<br />
<input type="submit" value="cargar" /> }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de usar un:

```
return View();
```

Coloca el nombre de la vista:

```
return View("NombreDeLaVista");
```

Para redireccionar a otra acción utiliza RedirectToAction para enviar a otra acción.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
```

Answer (score 1):

En el MVC puedes utilizar:

```
return View(@Nombre_vista)
return View(@Nombre_vista, @Model)

/// El nombre de método que retornas a la vista,
/// debe de tener el mismo nombre
//  que el nombre del archivo de tu vista
public ActionResult MiMetodo()
{
    return View();
}
```